# Search in model and in its relations and paginate results

Tags: mysql, search, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

So I'm building an ECommerce site using Laravel/MySQL, the product related tables I have are as follows: 'products', 'attributes', 'taxonomies' and 'tags'. When a user types a keyword to search for product, I want to search all 4 tables with one query to get the desired products, then I want to use Laravel paginate function to paginate the result, now how do I make it done in one query? Maybe some joins involved?

[image]

Here it is, the relationship of my database tables, as for my models, it is defined like this:

```
class Product extends Eloquent {
    ...
    public function taxonomies() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Taxonomy', 'product_taxonomy', 'product_id', 'taxonomy_id');
    }
    ...
    // Same goes for attributes and labels
    public function reviews() {
        return $this->hasMany('Review', 'product_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried and we'll help you to find the solution for your query

Comment: You can define your relations in your Eloquent model and then lazy load the relation when you call it.  If you post your table structure we can definitely help a little better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
$products = Product::where('name', 'LIKE ', '%' . $keyword . '%');

$products = $products->orWhereHas('attributes',
    function ($query) use ($keyword) {
        $query->where('name', 'LIKE ', '%' . $keyword . '%');
    }
);
$products = $products->orWhereHas('taxonomies',
    function ($query) use ($keyword) {
        $query->where('name', 'LIKE ', '%' . $keyword . '%');
    }
);
$products = $products->orWhereHas('tags', 
    function ($query) use ($keyword) {
        $query->where('name', 'LIKE ', '%' . $keyword . '%');
    }
);


$products = $products->paginate(10);
```

Now you look in product name and in names of your relations (tags, taxonomies and attributes) and paginate 10 products.

Comment: Right on! Exactly what I need. with models and relationships all setup, this one works like a charm! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @dulan Why you accepted other answer then?  You can accept only one answer from all answers. I see you've already changed accepted answer twice

Comment: Hmmm, sorry noob here... Will pay attention next time, thought those answers are close and wanna thank for their help...

Comment: @dulan So decide which is correct solution for your question and accept this one not the others. It will also help in future other users if they have similar problem

Comment: instead of writing `like` query if you write `match against` query it will be much more faster.

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this

```
$data = DB::table('products')
->join('attributes', 'products.attributes_id', '=', 'attributes.id')
->join('taxonomies', 'products.taxonomies_id', '=', 'taxonomies.id')
->join('tags', 'host_vulnerabilities.tags_id', '=', 'tags.id')
->where('products.id', '=', $id)
->select('products.id', 'attributes.name') //all required fields
->paginate(15);
```

I have just added sample example. Please update code as per your requirement

Comment: This is what I need, but sorry I forgot to mention that products and taxonomies are many-to-many relations, so I used pivot tables like product_taxonomy instead of putting taxonomy_id as foreign key in products table, so do attributes and tags, any thoughts?

Comment: Then create models to fetch data
you can use belongsToMany relationship for this 
Check this doc.
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent

Comment: So I went through the doc quickly, if I'm not mistaken, guess I should use querying relations like:
$products = Product::whereHas('taxonomies', function($q) {$q->where('taxonomy_name', 'like', '%' . $keyword .'%');}->whereHas('tags', function($q) {$q->where('tag_name', 'like', '%' . $keyword . '%');})->paginate(10);
yes?no?

Comment: Best way is to implement laravel model. or you can directly use raw() function and write sql query then use paginate function.

Comment: I did implement laravel model and all its relationships, would you be kind to tell me how exactly I should write the query in Laravel please? Or, if that's too much to ask, could you please point out which section of the doc falls into my situation exactly, the doc that you put down a link previously? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `UNION` for this,

```
SELECT product_id, product name FROM Products WHERE keyword = 'my_keyword' UNION 
SELECT product_id, product name FROM Attributes WHERE keyword = 'my_keyword' UNION
..... Same for other tables
```

Moreover it will filter out repeated results as `UNION` works as `UNION DISTINCT`. But if you provide us with a schema or some db structure, can provide a better solution.

For Laravel, this may work you can create a view and query the view instead of the actual tables, or create your Paginator manually:

```
$page = Input::get('page', 1);
$paginate = 10;
$w1 = 'my_keyword';

$first = DB::table('products')->where('attribute', 'like', '"%'.$w1.'%"');
$second = DB::table('attributes')->where('attribute', 'like', '"%'.$w1.'%"');
$third = DB::table('taxonomies')->where('attribute', 'like', '"%'.$w1.'%"');
$fourth = DB::table('tags')->where('attribute', 'like', '"%'.$w1.'%"');

$union1 = $first->union($second);
$union2 = $third->union($union1);
$union3 = $fourth->union($union2);
$union3->get();

$slice = array_slice($union3, $paginate * ($page - 1), $paginate);
$result = Paginator::make($slice, count($union3), $paginate);

return View::make('yourView',compact('result'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I'm sure this one works, yet I prefer a Laravel context workaround.

Comment: If I get this right, doesn't this fetch all possible products all at once? If so, then paginate loses its point I think？

Comment: please let me know issues as you have downvoted my answer, so i can improve my answer and learn.

Comment: Nothing's wrong, I am just confused with the upvote/downvote rule here and Marcin Nabiałek told me I can accept only one answer so...

Comment: Its okay dude, I am just happy I could help you.

Comment: I don't know how you find here product whose tags much term (assuming this product name doesn't match term). If you search for 'green' and you have 'green' only in this tag where you find product for this tag? Because if I understood well  OP he wanted to find the product whose tag matches this term and not the tag itself

Comment: Marcin, this is not exact code, it was just to help him with his logic. I guess logic is good here and this was ultimate aim of code.

Comment: @Rockse I understand but in my opinion it's not the best solution. You should use relationship searching and not query 4 tables

Comment: I understand but its a different approach to a same problem, I don't think it should be downvoted.